# AIR modal screen

Tags: air, adobe, modal-dialog

I am developing an AIR application where I need to display a Modal Window.
The screen should fill the entire desktop including the Task Bar.
If the user wants to exit the screen, he should press Windows+D option or activate Task Manager.
Can any one post some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Try the example here

http://flex4fun.com/2010/12/01/flex4-popupmanager-example-change-modal-color-and-click-modal-close-popup/

```
PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, TitleWindow, true)
```

last argument makes the popup "modal".

[http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html#createPopUp()](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html#createPopUp%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of taskbar, switch to fullscreen mode with

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

User always can switch to another window with Alt-Tab (on Windows), AIR cannot "lock" screen to prevent that.